# imadjust inbuilt matlab function for RGB image by using gamma parameter

Tags: matlab, image-processing

To make an adjustment to the contrast in an RGB image, how do you use a separate gamma value for each color channel? When I run the following code, I get this error:

> Error using imadjust>checkRange (line 298)
>   Function imadjust expected its third input argument, [LOW_OUT; HIGH_OUT]
>   to be a two-element vector or a 2-by-3 matrix.

```
img = imread('onion.png');
img = im2double(img);
gamma = [0.5,0.5,0.5];
out = imadjust(img, [.2 .3 0 ; .6 .7 1], gamma);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third input  is expected to be the lower and upper bounds on the output contrast. `gamma` is the *fourth* input so you'll want to pass an empty array `[]` as the third input followed by your `gamma` value.

```
out = imadjust(img,[.2 .3 0 ; .6 .7 1], [], 0.5);
```

[image]

Or if you want a separate `gamma` per channel.

```
gammas = [1 0.5 1];
out = imadjust(img,[.2 .3 0 ; .6 .7 1], [], gammas);
```

[image]

Comment: if i want set value for lower and upper bounds on the output contrast is this code correct? out = imadjust(img,[.2 .3 0 ; .6 .7 1], [ ? ], gammas); i want after adjustment dark pixels darker and brighter pixels brother.What value it should be a question mark

Comment: @Mohammad The third input will have a similar form to the second input and you'll have to look at the documentation to determine a reasonable value.

Comment: @ Suever thanks. but examples in documentation just for second input. im looking for a way that choosing best value for third input depended on image.